# get products from storage and compares amount

Tags: javascript

I need to get the total amount of custom products, and then compares to original product id, this is what i have for now... Thanks in advance. Edited:
I'm trying to get the sumatory amounts of storage_products with same _id.

This is my exptected output:

```js
[{_id: '123456789', customId: '', name: 'Apple', amount: 5}, {_id: '987654321', customId: '', name: Olives, amount: 0}];
```

```js
let storage_products = [
    {
        _id: '123456789',
        customId: 'abc123',
        name: 'Apple',
        amount: 2
    },
    {
        _id: '123456789',
        customId: 'asd456',
        name: 'Apple',
        amount: 3
    }
];

let db_products = [
    {
        _id: '123456789',
        customId: '',
        name: 'Apple',
        amount: 0
    },
    {
        _id: '987654321',
        customId: '',
        name: 'Olives',
        amount: 0
    }
];

/* 
Expected output = [{_id: '123456789', customId: '', name: 'Apple', amount: 5}, 
           {_id: '987654321', customId: '', name: Olives, amount: 0}]
*/

let actualProducts = db_products.map(obj => ({ ...obj, amount: Math.max(obj.amount, storage_products.find(obj2 => (obj2._id == obj._id))?.amount || 0) }));   

console.log(actualProducts)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code will set the total amount of the same items in both `storage_products` and `db_products`.

```js
let storage_products = [
    {
        _id: '123456789',
        customId: 'abc123',
        name: 'Apple',
        amount: 2
    },
    {
        _id: '123456789',
        customId: 'asd456',
        name: 'Apple',
        amount: 3
    }
];

let db_products = [
    {
        _id: '123456789',
        customId: '',
        name: 'Apple',
        amount: 0
    },
    {
        _id: '987654321',
        customId: '',
        name: 'Olives',
        amount: 0
    }
];

/* 
Expected output = [{_id: '123456789', customId: '', name: 'Apple', amount: 5}, 
           {_id: '987654321', customId: '', name: Olives, amount: 0}]
*/

let actualProducts = db_products.map(dbItem => ({
  ...dbItem, 
  amount: storage_products.reduce((amount, storageItem) => amount += dbItem._id === storageItem._id ? storageItem.amount : 0, dbItem.amount)
}));   

console.log(actualProducts)
```

Comment: @sonEtLumiere, does it work?

Comment: Yes! thank you so much!